# Error 403 on accessing localhost that is synced with dropbox on OS X

Tags: macos, xampp, synchronization, dropbox

I recently work with Windows 8.1 and El capitan in 2 different computers. I use dropbox to sync my project files that is located in dropbox which the dropbox itself located in htdocs. I have no problem working with windows. the dropbox folder is accessible from browser. but it doesn't work in my Mac, I have tried to allow all access via http.conf but it seems something else should be configured to allow me to access dropbox via my browser. anyone have experienced and fixed this before?

Comment: Keep in mind that the http server process needs access to all folders in the path leading to the actual documents, not only to the folder containing them itself.

Comment: Also you need to configure the access rules for your folders differently inside the http servers host configuration, since the paths are obviously completely different compared to the MS-Windows system.

Comment: just to make it clearer, I put my dropbox inside the htdocs (localhost/Dropbox/myproject)  both in windows and mac, meaning I don't have to configure both differently since it is treated as a folder that contain my files. I'm not sure this is how everyone sync a folder, but simply I just want to keep it synced.

Comment: The path of the location of that `htdocs` folder you use _certainly_ is different on those two operating systems. They use a completely different file system notation. That means you have to adapt at least the `DocumentRoot` command and the corresponding `<Directory ...>` section on your http servers host configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this issue. The problem is simply in accessibility of the Dropbox folder that is placed inside the Htdocs folder. I just change the the folder accessibility by changing it from folder info on mac. It's not as complicated as what I expected before. So, if you have problem in syncing your htdocs folder using dropbox, just change the folder permission by go to right clicks, get info and change it from no access to read and write. 
problem solved.

P.S 
if you want to sync only the files of your project without sync the database (Mysql) just put your dropbox folder inside the htdocs and it's done. if you experience the error 403 do what I have done in the description above.